# XSL: Apply a template after a math operation on element

Tags: xml, xslt

I must admit, I am a total noob. So, I apologize ahead of time, as I assume what I'm asking is fairly basic. I'm in the early learning phase right now so please bear with me.

**Sample XML Record:**

```
<ArrayOfMessage>
  <Message>
  ...
    <LocalTimestamp>130979673444601802</LocalTimestamp>
  ...
  </ArrayOfMessage>
</Message>
```

**Intended Goal:**

Divide 130979673444601802 by (10 * 1000 * 1000) - 11644473600. This equates to 1453497841.6748905; or, the equivalent Unix epoch time of the original value. I need this [epoch value](http://www.epochconverter.com/) so that I can then apply the date/time template below. The date/time format I'm hoping to arrive at is simply one I can use to sort by and one that is less cryptic (i.e. more readable).

```
<xsl:template match="LocalTimestamp">
   <xsl:value-of 
select='xs:dateTime("1970-01-01T00:00:00") + @stamp * xs:dayTimeDuration("PT0.001S")'/>
</xsl:template>
```

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please show us an example of the input and explain what do you want to see as the output - and why.

Comment: No problem, I've modified my original post. Hopefully that helps?

Comment: Still no sign of the expected (final) result of the transformation.

Comment: I don't see any attribute named `stamp` in that input sample.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I guess here in lies my primary issue.  I need to be able to at least perform the division mentioned so that I can then apply whatever dateTime expression is needed. Essentially, my goal is to apply the division to the original value, then apply the dateTime template (TBD).

Comment: @CaptainChaos Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, you want to do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="xs:dateTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00') + (. div 10000000 - 11644473600) * xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1S')"/>
```

Applied to a node with a value of `130979673444601802`, the result will be:

```
2016-01-22T20:15:44.46018
```

---

Of course, if you had made it clear from the beginning that the given number [represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601,](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/188768) it would have become obvious that the transition through Unix time is an unnecessary complication. You can convert the given number directly to a date by:

```
<xsl:value-of select="xs:dateTime('1601-01-01T00:00:00') + . div 10000000 * xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1S')"/>
```